# Color Ramp is not working for me 2.8

Tags: texturing, shaders

[image]

I'm trying to make a mask around the edges of the metal circles to look shiny wail having the wrest of the faces black/dark grey. So what I did was use the Input>Geometry and then use converter>ColorRamp (Color Ramp) to clamp the values together to get the edge to show up. No matter how I put it, it wont work...
 There shouldn't be wrong I'm doing I dont think, I'm following the exact instructions shown on a tutorial on the exact same thing Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYseMQDkPAI
If someone knows what the problem is please help me

Comment: I suspect it's because you're in "Look dev" shading rather than rendered shading. I can't test it myself right now, but try switching to rendered shading by clicking the fourth icon in the top right of the 3D view, the one partially hidden under the outliner.

Comment: make sure you reset scale the object pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because your render engine is not set to cycles. I know I'm a couple years late but maybe someone can find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the manual: [Geometry Node — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html#outputs):

> **Pointiness** `Cycles Only`
>
> An approximation of the curvature of the mesh per vertex. Lighter values indicate convex angles, darker values indicate concave angles. It allows you to do effects like dirt maps and wear-off effects.

Pointiness being a Cycles Only feature, you have to be in render shading and using Cycles render engine to see it. The material view is powered by Eevee render engine, hence you can't see it there either.